# Copy Access Database to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Access to SQL Server.  Using SQL Server Management Studio.

First apologies but one week of frustration and going round in circles. A 73 year old novice struggles.
Firstly I limited a table to only three rows and removed all Indexes - Including the Primary Key. It then became apparent that I was writing data back to the original table. Now I find that "The connection string has not been initialised" (Net Framework Data Provider for ODBC).  How do I Initialise this component ?
Thank you

Comment: I see you managed to get this working, but I can't accept your suggested edit as I don't have 2k reputation (yet).  Just to let you know, if the answer works then you should accept it.  This means that other people who have the same issue will be able to quickly find the accepted answer to their problem.  Glad this all worked out for you anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is incredibly unclear, but I will take a stab at answering what I think you are asking...

So I'm going to guess that you have an MS-Access database, and you wish to import this into SQL Server.  I have no idea which tool you are using to do this, or even if you are pushing data from Access into SQL Server or pulling it from SQL Server.  I'll assume the latter for now (as it's generally the best way).

Here's some basic steps for how you might achieve this:

- create an empty SQL Server database, i.e. no tables in it;
- in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS), navigate to your empty database, right-click it and select Tasks/ Import Data.  This launches the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard;
- click Next until you get to the page where you "choose a data source", which *might* be the first page if you previously disabled tips screens, etc.;
- in the data source drop-down you will find ".Net Framework Data Provider for Odbc", but don't use this data source, as there is a much better option for MS-Access further down;
- instead pick "Microsoft Access (Microsoft Jet Database Engine)";
- browse to your MS-Access database (*.mdb), entering a username/ password if the database is encrypted;
- click Next, to bring up the "choose a destination" page;
- pick the "SQL Server Native Client 11.0" destination choice.  If you don't have this then pick the highest version for "SQL Server Native Client" that you can find;
- enter the details of the empty SQL Server database you just created, i.e. the server it runs on and the name of the database;
- click Next, to bring up the "copy or query" page, pick "copy";
- click Next, to bring up the "select source tables/ views" page;
- pick the tables that you want to import from MS-Access into SQL Server;
- now just keep clicking Next until you can click Finish and run the Import.

There are many alternatives to this, e.g.:

- use "remote queries" from SQL Server to access your MS-Access database;
- export the data from MS-Access directly into SQL Server.  You can do this with copy/ paste if you link to the SQL Server database and add the empty tables you need to push data into, or you could write an MS-Access query;
- copy your MS-Access data into Excel, a CSV file, a TXT file, etc., then import this into SQL Server;
- write an application to run the data copy;
- use SSIS (integration services);
- use a 3rd party tool designed to copy data between RDBMSs, e.g. Red Gate.

I would suggest that you read the above, then you can maybe clarify your question, e.g.:

- what mechanism are you currently using to copy your data?
- where do you get the error message you quoted?
- is this for a single table, or are you planning to copy several tables;
- when you were writing data back to the original table then what tool were you using, and how did you identify this was the problem?
- etc...